# How can i calculate a string mix of operators and operands

Tags: java

It is giving error when operator is encountered in between.I know operator cannot be into
converted int or other format.I am using operator for calculation by reading byte codes and passing         it to enum defined.But as my string having operators so i am having prob in handling these.Please          help me on this.
----My Inputs is 1 + 2
----Expected Output-- 1 +  2=3---

Error in line ---- b = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());

--Error in during exceution-----
    Enter the series--
    1 + 2

```
no of tokens:3
yo
1
go
1
available

byte info:10
.......
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "+"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:484)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at Abc.main(Abc.java:42) 



I am not able to rectify it. Below is my code

import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Abc{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
System.out.println("Hello World");
System.out.println("Enter the series");
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s=br.readLine();
int a=0;
int b=0;
System.out.println(s);
while ((br.readLine()) != null) 
{
StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(s);

while (st.hasMoreTokens())
{
int i=0;
i=st.countTokens();
System.out.println("no of tokens:"+i);
String token = st.nextToken();
System.out.println("yo");
System.out.println(token);
System.out.println("go");


a=Integer.parseInt(token);
System.out.println(a);

 if (st.hasMoreTokens()) // before consuming another token, make sure 
         {
        System.out.println("available");
        byte b1=(byte)br.read();
        System.out.println("byte info:"+b1);
                         // there's one available
                         if (st.hasMoreTokens()){
              System.out.println(".......");
        b = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());  
         System.out.println("///////");

System.out.println(a);
System.out.println("reached");
System.out.println(b);
}
if (b1==43)
{
System.out.println("go");
int foo = Integer.parseInt(calculate(operator.ADDITION, a, b));
}
else if (b1==45)
{
int foo = Integer.parseInt(calculate(operator.SUBTRACTION, a, b));
}
else if (b1==42)
{
int foo = Integer.parseInt(calculate(operator.MULTIPLY, a, b));
}
else if (b1==47)
{
int foo = Integer.parseInt(calculate(operator.DIVIDE, a, b));
}

}
}
}
}

public enum operator
{
    ADDITION("+") {
        public int apply(int  x1, int x2) {
            return x1 + x2;
        }
    },
    SUBTRACTION("-") {
         public int apply(int x1, int x2) {
            return x1 - x2;
        }
    },
 MULTIPLY("*") {
         public int apply(int x1, int x2) {
            return x1 * x2;
        }
    },
     DIVIDE("/") {
         public int apply(int x1, int x2) {
            return x1 / x2;
        }
    };

 // You'd include other operators too...
private final String text;

    private operator(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    // Yes, enums *can* have abstract methods. This code compiles...
    public abstract int apply(int x1, int x2);

    public String toString() {
        return text;
    }

}

public static String calculate(operator op, int x1, int x2)
{
    return String.valueOf(op.apply(x1, x2));
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format your question and your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of Issues:

- You are just asking for input in string s but not processing it, hence rmeove that s variable and wherever its referenced.
- Define a `String line;` variable Modify and update your while loop as:

  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
- You dont need this line `byte b1=(byte)br.read();` as it will just have line feed i.e. enter key that you pressed when entering the line
- Your while loop should be:

  ```
  declare operand1, operand2, count as int
  declare operator as char
  while tokenizer has more tokens
  do
      optional validate String with token count as 3 with middle token as operator.
      read token
      if count == 0 then operand1 = int(token)
      else if count == 1 then operator = char(token)
     else operand2 = int(token)
  done
  ```

Comment: I am using string s variable below,passing it in stringtokenizer .how are diffrentiating between operators and operands (i.e.operator = char(token))this is my exact problem.

Comment: You are accepting parameter like a + b. So a is first token and is operand1, + is another and is operator, b is final and is operand2

Answer (score 0):

If you can do it, it would be much easier to use Java's `ScriptEngine` class to evaluate a user given string, like so:

```
ScriptEngineManager engine = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine javaScript = engine.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

System.out.print("Please enter a mathematical operation: ");
String op = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

try {
    Object a = javaScript.eval(op);
    System.out.println("Result: " + a.toString());
} catch (ScriptException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error in the input!");
}
```

I've tested it an it works fine.

Comment: @MohitDarmwal No problem. Consider marking it as accepted so when other people find this question they know what to do